# How to make laravel executable using Java?

Tags: java, php, mysql, laravel, user-interface

Any Idea/Suggestion how to wrap laravel so it becomes executable with Java Program?

So the idea is I'd like to create a GUI using Java for doing laravel command like serve, queue:work, migrate, etc. Thus the threads/processes are handled GUI-ly by Java.

But as we know, laravel requires so many prerequisites to be installed first, for instance, PHP and mySQL.

Wouldn't it be great to provide a GUI to control all of that? So all the administrators need to do, just extract my app, open the java GUI app, click start button, and voila! it's served.

Thank you in advance!

RESOLUTION:

Developing another app to run a standalone webserver is almost impossible if not impossible. So I decided to create a VM to run everything.

Comment: using REST api its possible

Comment: Ever heard of Vagrant box https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html. It does everything you are trying to do. And you can find plenty of boilerplates for vagrant boxes. Have a look at above link

Comment: IDEA . to use vegrant there is a file called `VagrantFile` which holds all the VM and dependencies config and commands. You can generate that file from your java code. and just do `vagrant up` and your Laravel installation will be ready.